# iPad Retina Display specific media queries

Tags: ios, css, wordpress, ipad, media-queries

I've been using Apple's Xcode tool (iOS Simulator) to code iPad views. I can't target landscape view on the iPad Retina device.
I've been trying the following media queries...

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width 
: 1024px) and   (orientation : landscape) and ( -webkit-min-device-
pixel-ratio: 2){  //style goes here// }

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 1536px) and (max-device-width 
: 2048px) and   (orientation : landscape) and ( -webkit-min-device-
pixel-ratio: 2){  //style goes here// }
```

**I can't find any other way to target the landscape view in iPad Retina. I have even tried this code in different parts of the CSS file, still no luck at all.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just realized my **FTP program was not working correctly** when I entered the editor inside the Wordpress dashboard (the query was not there) so I manually wrote it dawn directly on my theme's CSS file **and it worked**.This FTP program stole hours from me.. but `the query was right and the meta tag as well.`

All in all, for anyone experiencing issues while coding new iPads Retina displays (32 and 64 bits), they should include **the meta viewport** in their headers:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

and the **corresponding query** (Landscape view, in this case)is:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width 
: 1024px) and   (orientation : landscape) and ( -webkit-min-device-
pixel-ratio: 2){  //style goes here// }
```

Answer (score 2):

The first one is correct, i use the same media query and is working on a real device.
Maybe you forgot to include the meta viewport?

Comment: +1, that's the most common cause of issues with media queries.

Comment: Maybe, How should I include it? @Usse I'm using several media queries on my CSS file, and they all work fine. I have already coded iphone both views.

Comment: The common meta viewport for responsive layout is:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
If you can test on a real device you can check if is a problem related to the simulator.

Comment: I'm developing in wordpress. So you're telling me that I should include in my header.php file the following line: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">` just like that, so that the media query is recognised? @Usse

Comment: You need the viewport meta tag to properly trigger the media queries (check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: Im currently using  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />` **My code renders fine on iPads which are not retina display, the problem is on the latest retina models**.